# How to undo modification/update on document in mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I have mistakenly modified document in collection by running the command

```
db.getCollection('Persons').update(
    // query 
    {

    },

    // update 
    {
       "Branch":"computer"
    },

    // options 
    {
        "multi" : false,  // update only one document 
        "upsert" : false  // insert a new document, if no existing document match the query 
    }
);
```

It had removed all fields in my first document except _id field in Persons collection.

The above command has resulted in

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5527636be4b0b3959623d6f7"),
    "Branch" : "computer"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5527637ee4b0b3959623d6f8"),
    "name" : "rajnish",
    "country" : "Bhutan"
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("552d133b44aef0215235e3e9"),
    "name" : "amol",
    "country" : "india"
}
```

so I basically wanted to undo modification. How do I do it.?

Comment: I do not want to store .. MongoDB automatically stores it. The above command had removed the fields name and country . so I wanted to undo modification. How do i do ?? do u have any idea ?

Comment: Yep! I have added solution, kindly see if that help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few things, which you can do:

> 1. Delete that first entry which stores "Branch": "Computer", with:

```
db.collection.remove({'_id': ObjectId("5527636be4b0b3959623d6f7")})
```

> 2. You can delete the whole collection, and start fresh, with:

```
db.collection.remove({})
```

**OR**

```
db.collection.drop()
```

> 3. Even, if you don't want to delete the incorrect entry, you can update it as:

```
db.collection.update({'_id': ObjectId("5527636be4b0b3959623d6f7")}, {'name': 'Gaurav', 'country': 'India'})
```

> 4. If you update, only the fields specified will be store and rest will be cleared out. So, you have to use $set as in:

```
db.collection.update({'_id': ObjectId("5527636be4b0b3959623d6f7")},{ $set: {'name': 'Gaurav', 'country': 'India'}},{upsert: true})
```

See, that helps.

Comment: That is not the feasible solution you provided .. BTW thanks for your efforts.

Comment: Why do you think it is not feasible?

Comment: dropping whole collection is not feasible .. I have services running on that data .. what if I have thousand of document in collection. dropping thousands of documents and starting fresh is not feasible for me. secondly for your second answer what if I have multiple fields, embedded documents, multiple arrays in one document. So second solution is also not feasible. I just wanted to undo what i have done mistakenly. Is it not possible ?

Comment: No, you can't undo but my point 4, basically tells you what update function can do, and how you take precautions. One more thing, if you have large DB and if it is live than it is better to take backup, so that if you screw things, you can restore with recent backup. That. would be feasible.